# Page not found - No umbraco document matches the url

Tags: umbraco, master-pages, umbraco6

When typing in a url that does not exist I want to display a custom 404 page however when I type in a non-existing page I am seeing a **Page not found No umbraco document matches the url** in the browser

At present I am to running multiple websites in one umbraco v6.2.5 application and there are multiple languages for each website for example the following:

```
 - www.mydomain.com/en 
 - www.mydomain.com/de
 - www.mydomain.com/fr
```

The config\404handlers.config consists of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NotFoundHandlers>
  <notFound assembly="umbraco" type="SearchForAlias" />
  <notFound assembly="umbraco" type="SearchForTemplate"/>
  <notFound assembly="umbraco" type="SearchForProfile"/>
  <notFound assembly="uComponents.NotFoundHandlers" type="MultiSitePageNotFoundHandler" />
  <notFound assembly="umbraco" type="handle404"/>
</NotFoundHandlers>
```

The document type and template have been created and the template has been assigned to the new 404 node but it is still not working.

I can see that the issue is related to the subdomain as when I remove these (i.e en/, de/, fr/) from the culture and hostnames the 404 page starts working but this is required to differentiate between the languages..

Can someone please suggest how I can get the 404 page to work with the subdomains, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this solution from Umbraco forums?
 https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/3857-Custom-404-pages-on-a-multilingual-site-doesn't-work#comment-72197

The whole thread could be useful, since a lot of people faced the same issues:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/3857-Custom-404-pages-on-a-multilingual-site-doesn't-work

Comment: Hi Marko looks promising, hopefully find a solution on that thread thanks!

Comment: Hey man, no problem. Let me know if you managed to solve it. :)